# hibernate/jpa metamodel classes do not include all fields

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am having this super irritating issue with my hibernate/jpa app I'm developing using maven and editing in eclipse.

I have my target/metamodel location set up in Properties > compiler > annotation processing, and it's all working fine, except for one class, where the metamodel class only contains the id.

Here is the entity:

```
@Entity
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String username;
private String password;

@Transient
private Authorization authorization;
// getters/setters omitted, but I do have them in the entity class
}
```

and here is the metamodel class

```
@Generated(value="Dali", date="2019-06-22T11:49:45.797-0400")
@StaticMetamodel(User.class)
public class User_ {
     public static volatile SingularAttribute<User, Integer> id;
}
```

This issue *only* occurs in the User class, all other classes are fine. I am getting compile errors in my DAO where I try to get a user with username/pw, and those fields do not exist in the metamodel class.

Any ideas what would cause this? 
Working on linux, compiler set to 1.8. 
thanks

## update

I ended up solving it by adding an entry for the entity in persistence.xml

```
<class>com.mypack.model.User</class>
```

I had gone thru the process of creating the entity and doing crud save, update, delete, and get by id functions, without the persistence.xml entries. I think I started with a few, found I didn't need them and commented them out.

Seeing now that when I try to create a criteriabuilder/root/query, etc, I run into that issue. Adding the entity to persistence.xml seems to have resolved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may be Dali generator's fault. I tried with hibernate-jpamodelgen through regular maven plugin and it works fine.

I suggest you do the same: it works, and everyone working on the project will benefit from it, you won't have to commit generated sources or tell everyone to configure Eclipse in the same way.

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <compilerArguments>
          <processor>org.hibernate.jpamodelgen.JPAMetaModelEntityProcessor</processor>
        </compilerArguments>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3.Final</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```